# data_bag_item to retrieve single keyvalue

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, databags

I just started playing with chef today, and one thing I can't wrap my head around is how I can use data bags to store multiple key-values in one item (1 bag > 1 item > many key-values) and be able to invoke them one by one within a recipe.

Here is a simple test to delete directory if the directory from databag exists.

```
directory 'bag_item[installvar.testbag]['testdir'])' do
  action :delete
  only_if { Dir.exist?(bag_item[installvar.testbag]['testdir']) }
end
```

Obviously I'm not using the index right but I'm not strong in ruby at all, I didn't know what ruby was until couple of weeks ago... all the googling points me at examples of mass usage on multiple items by one key-value, which is not what I am trying to achieve. databag is installvar itemID is testbag and the key I'm looking to retrieve is testdir.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html for some very basic Ruby introductions. Specifically look at the Hash section, as the item returned by the `data_bag_item()` method call acts like a Hash in most ways. Each bag item is a JSON-compatible hash at heart.

Answer (score 0):

so the solution is simple:

```
var = data_bag_item('installvar', 'testbag')
  dir = var['testdir']

directory "#{dir}" do
  action :delete
  only_if  Dir.exist?("#{['dir']}")
end
```

this works.

Comment: You can/should omit the `only_if` clause. Chef would only try to delete the directory, if it exists.

Comment: that makes total sense, this a reflex :) to put checks everywhere... thanks for pointing out.